# Custom domain SSL certificate in IBM Cloud

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to upload a custom domain SSL certificate to be used in IBM Cloud cloud foundry organization. I upload the certificate (PEM), the private key and the intermediate certificate... then I get the "processing" status but after some minutes the domain entry in the table goes back to the upload SSL Certificate option.

I am getting no warning or mail error. How can I know what is going wrong with the files uploaded?

Comment: Still an issue?

Comment: Yes. The certificate files are marked as OK (green checkmark) when I upload them, but the *.eu-gb.mybluemix.net certificate is returned by IBM Cloud when I perform the request. We decided to stick to a standalone reverse proxy in an external service and point our domain there, but this makes the full app perform much slower.

Comment: Could you add more details? I have wildcard domains (Let's Encrypt) working both with Cloud Foundry and Kubernetes. I only uploaded the certificate and key.

Comment: Yes, I used wildcard domain. Does  it anyway work for you? (I uploaded the intermediate certificate too)

Comment: Yes, it works for me, see my recent posts: https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/07/bringing-lets-encrypt-ibm-cloud.html and https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/07/secure-apps-on-ibm-cloud-kubernetes.html